# CALayer not properly set as per dragged position on Video when export

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, calayer

I am trying to put text on video with using CALayer, I have one view which is draggable, so i want to export video with text with exact position and text size as per video resolution,

[image]

Right now, when I export video with this position the result video is look like this one

[image]

```
    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    let videoLayer = CALayer()

    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width,height: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height)
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width, height:clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height)


    let backgroundLayer = CALayer()
    backgroundLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width, height: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height)
    backgroundLayer.position = CGPointMake(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width / 2.0, clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height / 2.0)

    backgroundLayer.addSublayer(supplyView.layer)
    backgroundLayer.masksToBounds = true

    for (index, view) in views.enumerate(){
        var layer = CALayer()
        layer = view.layer
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: supplyView.frame.origin.x, y: supplyView.frame.origin.y, width: supplyView.frame.size.width, height: supplyView.frame.size.height)

        layer.beginTime = CFTimeInterval(Float(startingDurations[index]))
        layer.duration = CFTimeInterval(Float(endingDurations[index]))
        layer.setAffineTransform(view.transform)
        layer.addAnimation(fadeAnimation, forKey: "scale")
        backgroundLayer.addSublayer(layer)
        print(index)
    }
    backgroundLayer.geometryFlipped = true
    parentLayer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)

    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
    let videoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: clipVideoTrack)
    let videoAssetTrack = mixComposition.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo).first

    videoLayerInstruction.setTransform((videoAssetTrack?.preferredTransform)!, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    videoLayerInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, atTime: videoAsset.duration)
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [videoLayerInstruction]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should translate coordinates of your text label to video frame coordinate system.

For example your videoLayer frame is (0, 0, 200, 200)

Real video frame can be (0,0, 640,...)

In this case text label with coordinates (100,100) will be moved up and left in your video. Label coordinates should be (300,300) to keep same position as in view

Comment: But how i calculate this coordinates of textlabel position from videoLayer? @Evgeniy Gushchin

Comment: @VivekGoswami It depends on how do you get a video. If you use AVCaptureSession to take video you can set SampleBufferDelegate for Video output and get dimension of video frame from CMSampleBuffer in delegate method `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`

If you get video as asset by url you can use next code

`guard let track = AVURLAsset(url: url).tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first else { return nil }
let size = track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)`

Comment: Actually I am select a video from photos which is pre-recorded or captured, This text label i have added in a view and that view i am dragging on videoview, i got AVAssets video size but how to set this text label x,y position and also its size on video because this label is resizable. @Evgeniy Gushchin

Comment: @VivekGoswami you should calculate scale between video size and view size. Then use the scale to transform text label coordinates and size.
e.g video size to times bigger then view size. So scale = 2. in this case you should multiply coordinates and size values on 2

Comment: Ok Thanks, Let me try with this I'll multiply size of view to set. @Evgeniy Gushchin